# Exact match file extension filter using grep

Tags: regex, linux, grep

I am working on running cat on all files with JS/JSX/SCALA extensions, I've tried the following

```
git ls-files | grep ".[js|jsx|scala]$"
git ls-files | grep ".*js|jsx|scala"
```

The end result will eventually look like this

```
git ls-files | grep -e ".*[js|jsx|scala]$" | xargs cat | wc -l
```

But I keep getting more files like yaml, yml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a group:

```
git ls-files | grep -E '\.(js|jsx|scala)$'
```

The `\.(js|jsx|scala)$` pattern matches a dot and then `js`, `jsx` or `scala` and then the end of string.

Mind the `-E` option enabling POSIX ERE compliance.

Comment: I think you could shorten it to `\.(jsx?|scala)$`

Comment: Yes, it is possible with POSIX ERE, but it is less readable.